# Unix Processes Diagram confusion

Tags: unix, process

[image]

Can you tell me what is the difference between the two red arrows in Unix process diagram?
Why preempted process goes directly to User Running without rescheduling? I don't quite get it. Why Preempted and Ready to Run In Memery are connected with dashed line?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not off topic in my opinion. This question went to my mind while studying before Unix <<Programming>> test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A preempted process *is* ready to run in memory, which is why there is a dashed line between the Preempted and Ready to Run in Memory states on this diagram.  A CPU-intensive process typically is doing work and using the CPU for an entire time slice, until a timer tick fires at the hardware level and causes the kernel to preempt the process.  That doesn't make the process any less ready to run, because in the act of preempting the process the kernel saves all the datastructures it needs for a context switch.

However, a preempted process isn't necessarily ready to run in *user mode*.  Instead, the kernel may preempt itself, because the kernel is doing some work when a network packet arrives, or a disk read completes, or the timer tick fires, or some other event causes preemption.  If the process was originally running in user mode when it was preempted (the situation I describe in the first paragraph), then it returns to user mode whenever the scheduler decides it should run again.  That's the leftmost red arrow.  On the other hand, if the process was preempted while running in kernel mode, it returns to kernel mode whenever the scheduler decides it should run again.  That's the other red arrow.

Comment: @MaciejZiarko The scheduler controls when *all* processes run, so in both cases the scheduler is invoked before the process picks up running again.  However, the difference is between running in user mode (via "return to user") and running in kernel mode (via "reschedule").

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean and you really helped me. But I think that this part of diagram is confusing. Thanks!

Comment: Diagram suggests that running user process is preempted through kernel mode (no direct arrow to preempetd) but when going back to running user it doesn't need kernel mode. Is it true? Does scheduler run in kernel model? I think so.

Comment: @MaciejZiarko The scheduler *does* run in kernel mode, and the kernel manages the transition between user mode and kernel mode.  So to get back to user mode the kernel does do some work.  I think the diagram would be more clear if the Preempted and Ready to Run in Memory states were combined into a single state.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the diagram is bogus. There should be an end to zombie processes, but there isn't. Otherwise zombie proceeses would accumulate and they don't.

Comment: All completed processes are zombies until they are reaped by their parent processes.

Comment: Yes, but given a state-diagram, one would expact **all the states**, incuding final/terminal states, even if they are of the kind *end of state*.

Comment: There is no state after the process is destroyed, which is what happens when its been reclaimed by the parent after it had been completed.

Comment: Bullshit. There is a transition (out of it) so there is a (non existent) state. Let's call it the epsilon-state.